# How to assign a interface{} to another interface{} whose concrete type is SameStructType?

Tags: go, reflection, interface

```
type SameStructType struct{
    Test string
}

func A() interface{} {
    return SameStructType{
        Test:"123",
    }
}
func B() interface{} {
    return &SameStructType{}
}

a:=A()
b:=B()

// *b=a //I want to make b assigned by a.
```

If I know the actual type, I can use the code below:

```
a := A().(SameStructType)
b := B().(*SameStructType)
*b = a
```

The question is I don't know their actual type,but I know they have the same type.

Is there an easy way instead of using "reflect"?
I don't like parsing the struct "field by field" using reflect because it is slow.

If I have to use reflect,is there an easy way?
I am sure that they have the same type,so is there a fast way to copy memory like C/C++?

Comment: *"Is there a easy way instead of using "reflect"?"* -- Nope, use `reflect` if you don't know the type and can't do type assertions.

Comment: If I have to use reflect,is there an easy way? I am sure that they have the same type,so is there a fast way to copy memory like C/C++?

Comment: `reflect.ValueOf(b).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(a))` (assuming `b` is of type `*T` and `a` of `T`). Keep in mind that this is a _shallow_ copy, just like `*b = a`, in your type-assert example, is a shallow copy.

Comment: Thank you . It works enough and well for me. the struct doesn't contains any pointer or interface, so "shallow copy" is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "stupid" way.

```
a := A()
b := B()
buffer, _ := json.Marshal(a)
json.Unmarshal(buffer, b)
```

It works "well", json package using reflect to encode/decode the interface{}.
I think this solution is easy for coding but slow for running,so I don't think it is a good solution.

Comment: There's no reason to write code like this.